# Cakephp 3 email validation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Guys folowing cakephp3 documentation for validation i try to validate my email field but that validation not work good.

**How this can be valid email?**

- a#53%#sdasd@gmail.com
- %321&%$sd@gmail.com

Form is successfull submited and data is saved to database. I think this validation is not good bcs i never see in my live email address like this above.

```
return $validator->requirePresence('email')
            ->notEmpty('email', __('Email is required field'))
            ->add('email', 'validFormat', [
                'rule' => 'email',
                'message' => 'E-mail must be valid'
            ]);
```

Comment: Just because you've never seen them, doesn't mean that they aren't valid. What you are showing here is perfectly valid. **https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local_part**

Comment: These are valid email addresses so the validator is correct!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you can find regular expression that Cake uses for email validation:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Validation/Validation.php#L567

If it does not satisfy your needs you can always provide your own.

Take a look on Email validation rule in CakePHP sources:

```
 public static function email($check, $deep = false, $regex = null)
```

You can provide your own regular expression like this:

```
$validator->add("email", "validFormat", [
    "rule" => ["email", false, $yourRegexp],
    "message" => "Email must be valid."
])
```